# Removing `^` from `s/^/1/;` causes my code to fail. Why?

Tags: regex, perl

I've been working on [this problem](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/35310/write-the-whole-of-the-holed-using-the-unholed) over at the code golf exchange which is why my code looks so funny.

Here's a program with `use strict` and `use warnings` that recreates the problem:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

$_ = "";

for my $i (1..33){
    s//1/;   # Just prepends 1 to the string $_
}
print "$_\n";

for my $i (34..127) {
    if( chr(y/1/1/) !~ /[!"'()*+,-.\/12357:;<=>?CEFGHIJKLMNSTUVWXYZ[\\\]^_`cfhijklmnrstuvwxyz{|}~]/ ) {
        print chr y/1/1/;
    }
    s/^/1/;   # Prepends 1 to the start of the string.
}
```

Here is the output:

```
111111111111111111111111111111111
#$%&04689@ABDOPQRabdegopq
```

This works as I would expect. However, when I take `^` out of the second regex, the regex no longer matches and lengthens the string.

```
use strict;
use warnings;

$_ = "";

for my $i (1..33){
    s//1/;
}
print "$_\n";

for my $i (34..127) {
    if( chr(y/1/1/) !~ /[!"'()*+,-.\/12357:;<=>?CEFGHIJKLMNSTUVWXYZ[\\\]^_`cfhijklmnrstuvwxyz{|}~]/ ) {
        print chr y/1/1/;
    }
    s//1/;   # No Longer matches!
}
```

Why does this happen? `s//1/` works in the first loop, so why does changing it in the second one break everything?

For an additional point of confusion, if you put the if block in braces, the regex matches again:

```
for my $i (34..127) {
    {
        if( chr(y/1/1/) !~ /[!"'()*+,-.\/12357:;<=>?CEFGHIJKLMNSTUVWXYZ[\\\]^_`cfhijklmnrstuvwxyz{|}~]/ ) {
            print chr y/1/1/;
        }
    }
    s//1/;   # This prepends 1 to the string $_ again.
}
```

### edit:

I wanted to edit my original code back into the question for reference:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
$_="";
until( y/1/1/ > 32){
    print "test1";
    s//1/;
    print "test";
}
print "$_\n";
until( y/1/1/ > 125+1 ) {
    if( chr(y/1/1/) !~ /[!"'()*+,-.\/12357:;<=>?CEFGHIJKLMNSTUVWXYZ[\\\]^_`cfhijklmnrstuvwxyz{|}~]/ ) {
        print chr y/1/1/;
    }

    s/^/1/; # this is the line we remove ^ from
}
```

When we remove `^` from the line, the output changes from:

```
test1testtest1testtest1testtest1testtest1testtest1testtest1testtest1testtest1testtest1testtest1testtest1testtest1testtest1testtest1testtest1testtest1testtest1testtest1testtest1testtest1testtest1testtest1testtest1testtest1testtest1testtest1testtest1testtest1testtest1testtest1testtest1testtest1test111111111111111111111111111111111
#$%&04689@ABDOPQRabdegopq
```

to

> **hanging with no output**

So in this case, the line change in the second loop changes the behavior of the first one it seems.

Comment: since we've figured out its the magical empty pattern, you might want to change the title to include words `empty regex pattern s//1/` :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To expand on VladimirM answer

```
print "regex have dynamic scope\n";
$_ = 1;
{
    m/1/;
    s//2/;
    print "$_  one becomes two, s//2/ is really s/1/2/\n";
}
$_=1;
{
    m/1/;
    {
        s//2/;
    }
    print "$_  one still becomes two, s//2/ is really s/1/2/\n";
}

$_=1;
{
    {
        m/1/;
    }
    s//2/;
    print "$_  one becomes twentyone, s//2/; is really s/(?:)//2;\n";
}

__END__
regex have dynamic scope
2  one becomes two, s//2/ is really s/1/2/
2  one still becomes two, s//2/ is really s/1/2/
21  one becomes twentyone, s//2/; is really s/(?:)//2;
```

since regex have dynamic scope, using  [The empty pattern //](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#The-empty-pattern-//)  really means using the previous pattern from same  [dynamic scope](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlglossary.html#dynamic-scoping)  so don't do that :)

If you add `use re 'debug';` you can see the regex engine use the previous pattern (focus on `Matching REx` statements, `NOTHING(2)` is empty without previous, `EXACT <1>(3)` is the previous pattern)

```
regex have dynamic scope
Guessing start of match in sv for REx "1" against "1"
Found anchored substr "1" at offset 0...
Guessed: match at offset 0
Guessing start of match in sv for REx "1" against "1"
Found anchored substr "1" at offset 0...
Guessed: match at offset 0
Matching REx "1" against "1"
   0 <> <1>                  |  1:EXACT <1>(3)
   1 <1> <>                  |  3:END(0)
Match successful!
2  one becomes two, s//2/ is really s/1/2/
Guessing start of match in sv for REx "1" against "1"
Found anchored substr "1" at offset 0...
Guessed: match at offset 0
Guessing start of match in sv for REx "1" against "1"
Found anchored substr "1" at offset 0...
Guessed: match at offset 0
Matching REx "1" against "1"
   0 <> <1>                  |  1:EXACT <1>(3)
   1 <1> <>                  |  3:END(0)
Match successful!
2  one still becomes two, s//2/ is really s/1/2/
Guessing start of match in sv for REx "1" against "1"
Found anchored substr "1" at offset 0...
Guessed: match at offset 0
Matching REx "" against "1"
   0 <> <1>                  |  1:NOTHING(2)
   0 <> <1>                  |  2:END(0)
Match successful!
21  one becomes twentyone, s//2/; is really s/(?:)//2;
```

**update:** because you have an infinite loop; last pattern always has 1 in it, so the substitution is essentially s/1/1/; which means your string doesn't grow, its always 33 chars ... see update :)

```
$_="";
until( y/1/1/ > 32){
    print "test1";
    s//1/;
    print "test";
}
print "$_\n";
my $max = 126;
my $count = 0;
my $reps = 0;
until( y/1/1/ > 125+1 ) {
    if( chr(y/1/1/) !~ /[!"'()*+,-.\/12357:;<=>?CEFGHIJKLMNSTUVWXYZ[\\\]^_`cfhijklmnrstuvwxyz{|}~]/ ) {
        print chr y/1/1/;
    }
$reps =
#~     s/^/1/; # win
    s//1/; # fail
    $count++;
    last if $count > $max;
}
print "m $max c $count r $reps l @{[ length $_ ]}\n";
__END__
win #$%&04689@ABDOPQRabdegopqm 126 c 94 r 1 l 127
fail m 126 c 127 r 1 l 33
```

Unless you're obfuscating append is `$_ .= 1;` and prepend is `$_ = 1 . $_;`

Comment: Thanks, this makes sense. Your example is clear on how the empty match works. Have you tried running my original code? (Miller took it out with his edit but I put it back in). I still don't understand why changing the regex in the second loop affects the output from the first loop.

Comment: because you have an infinite loop; last pattern always has 1 in it, so the substitution is essentially s/1/1/; which means your string doesn't grow, its always 33 chars ... see update

Answer (score 5):

`s//1/;` does not check for any or empty string. It checks against the last successful regex text before. So, the first loop uses default regex and the second one uses the last successful check from the `if` above.

Quote:

> If the PATTERN evaluates to the empty string, the last successfully
>   matched regular expression is used instead. In this case, only the g
>   and c flags on the empty pattern are honored

Please, see [The empty pattern //](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#Regexp-Quote-Like-Operators)

Comment: Interesting point, but that's not a sufficient explanation.  If one changes the regex to: `s//^/; print "$i $_\n";`, one can observe that the regex is matching and modifying `$_`, but the change does not persist through the loop.  Additionally, this does not explain the fact that the extra braces around the `if` statement removes the bug.

Answer (score 1):

To expand a second time on [VladimirM](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3011079/vladimirm)'s [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25027118/1733163) that the [`empty pattern //`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#Regexp-Quote-Like-Operators) is the problem, the following is from perldoc:

> - The empty pattern `//`
>
>   If the `PATTERN` evaluates to the empty string, the last successfully matched regular expression is used instead. In this case, only the `g` and `c` flags on the empty pattern are honored; the other flags are taken from the original pattern. If no match has previously succeeded, this will (silently) act instead as a genuine empty pattern (which will always match).

Basically, if there is another regex within the same scope that matched, then the LHS of the regex with the empty pattern will actually be the LHS of the previous regex.

In the below example inspired by the OP, I expand the string using the ones digit of the incrementer instead.  However, once the other regex matches `chr(33)` which is a exclamation point, the LHS of the empty regex will change.  It will then start matching the digits `12357` and replacing them with our ones place of the incrementer.  Therefore the string will stay the same length from then on.

```
use strict;
use warnings;

$_ = "";

for my $i (1..127) {
    my $chr = chr(length);

    if( $chr =~ m'(?![#$%&])[[:punct:]12357CE-NS-Zcfh-nr-z]' ) {
        print "'$chr'";
    } else {
        print "   ";
    }

    s//$i % 10/e;

    printf "% 4d %s\n", $i, $_;
}
```

The following output clearly demonstrates this:

```
      1 1
      2 21
      3 321
      4 4321
      5 54321
      6 654321
      7 7654321
      8 87654321
      9 987654321
     10 0987654321
     11 10987654321
     12 210987654321
     13 3210987654321
     14 43210987654321
     15 543210987654321
     16 6543210987654321
     17 76543210987654321
     18 876543210987654321
     19 9876543210987654321
     20 09876543210987654321
     21 109876543210987654321
     22 2109876543210987654321
     23 32109876543210987654321
     24 432109876543210987654321
     25 5432109876543210987654321
     26 65432109876543210987654321
     27 765432109876543210987654321
     28 8765432109876543210987654321
     29 98765432109876543210987654321
     30 098765432109876543210987654321
     31 1098765432109876543210987654321
     32 21098765432109876543210987654321
     33 321098765432109876543210987654321
'!'  34 421098765432109876543210987654321
'!'  35 451098765432109876543210987654321
'!'  36 461098765432109876543210987654321
'!'  37 467098765432109876543210987654321
'!'  38 468098765432109876543210987654321
'!'  39 468098965432109876543210987654321
'!'  40 468098960432109876543210987654321
'!'  41 468098960412109876543210987654321
'!'  42 468098960422109876543210987654321
'!'  43 468098960432109876543210987654321
'!'  44 468098960442109876543210987654321
'!'  45 468098960445109876543210987654321
'!'  46 468098960446109876543210987654321
'!'  47 468098960446709876543210987654321
'!'  48 468098960446809876543210987654321
'!'  49 468098960446809896543210987654321
'!'  50 468098960446809896043210987654321
'!'  51 468098960446809896041210987654321
'!'  52 468098960446809896042210987654321
'!'  53 468098960446809896043210987654321
'!'  54 468098960446809896044210987654321
'!'  55 468098960446809896044510987654321
'!'  56 468098960446809896044610987654321
'!'  57 468098960446809896044670987654321
'!'  58 468098960446809896044680987654321
'!'  59 468098960446809896044680989654321
'!'  60 468098960446809896044680989604321
'!'  61 468098960446809896044680989604121
'!'  62 468098960446809896044680989604221
'!'  63 468098960446809896044680989604321
'!'  64 468098960446809896044680989604421
'!'  65 468098960446809896044680989604451
'!'  66 468098960446809896044680989604461
'!'  67 468098960446809896044680989604467
'!'  68 468098960446809896044680989604468
'!'  69 468098960446809896044680989604468
'!'  70 468098960446809896044680989604468
'!'  71 468098960446809896044680989604468
'!'  72 468098960446809896044680989604468
'!'  73 468098960446809896044680989604468
'!'  74 468098960446809896044680989604468
'!'  75 468098960446809896044680989604468
'!'  76 468098960446809896044680989604468
'!'  77 468098960446809896044680989604468
'!'  78 468098960446809896044680989604468
'!'  79 468098960446809896044680989604468
'!'  80 468098960446809896044680989604468
'!'  81 468098960446809896044680989604468
'!'  82 468098960446809896044680989604468
'!'  83 468098960446809896044680989604468
'!'  84 468098960446809896044680989604468
'!'  85 468098960446809896044680989604468
'!'  86 468098960446809896044680989604468
'!'  87 468098960446809896044680989604468
'!'  88 468098960446809896044680989604468
'!'  89 468098960446809896044680989604468
'!'  90 468098960446809896044680989604468
'!'  91 468098960446809896044680989604468
'!'  92 468098960446809896044680989604468
'!'  93 468098960446809896044680989604468
'!'  94 468098960446809896044680989604468
'!'  95 468098960446809896044680989604468
'!'  96 468098960446809896044680989604468
'!'  97 468098960446809896044680989604468
'!'  98 468098960446809896044680989604468
'!'  99 468098960446809896044680989604468
'!' 100 468098960446809896044680989604468
'!' 101 468098960446809896044680989604468
'!' 102 468098960446809896044680989604468
'!' 103 468098960446809896044680989604468
'!' 104 468098960446809896044680989604468
'!' 105 468098960446809896044680989604468
'!' 106 468098960446809896044680989604468
'!' 107 468098960446809896044680989604468
'!' 108 468098960446809896044680989604468
'!' 109 468098960446809896044680989604468
'!' 110 468098960446809896044680989604468
'!' 111 468098960446809896044680989604468
'!' 112 468098960446809896044680989604468
'!' 113 468098960446809896044680989604468
'!' 114 468098960446809896044680989604468
'!' 115 468098960446809896044680989604468
'!' 116 468098960446809896044680989604468
'!' 117 468098960446809896044680989604468
'!' 118 468098960446809896044680989604468
'!' 119 468098960446809896044680989604468
'!' 120 468098960446809896044680989604468
'!' 121 468098960446809896044680989604468
'!' 122 468098960446809896044680989604468
'!' 123 468098960446809896044680989604468
'!' 124 468098960446809896044680989604468
'!' 125 468098960446809896044680989604468
'!' 126 468098960446809896044680989604468
'!' 127 468098960446809896044680989604468
```

Comment: Great example Miller! At this point, I would say that the empty pattern should probably be kept out of production code in most cases.